# Mouse initializing at the BIOS takes long

Tags: bios, mouse

I'm on an **Acer Aspire 5738ZG laptop** with a **Phoenix BIOS v. 1.34**. It's loading for about **15** seconds and I wondered if I could reduce that time.

In the setup I have found and disabled **Quiet boot** (no logo and more info) and saw that it **stops** at a point for about 5-6 secs and then says "**Mouse Initialized**". Why is it taking so long to initialize a mouse? And why is it doing that at all, the BIOS and all setting (at least mine) don't require a mouse. Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just opened my laptop and disconnected and reconnected the mouse. After I turned on the laptop it loaded up as normal.